# html/css : fixed divs overlapping with content divs

Tags: html, css

trying to learn some html/css and I'm having a problem with fixed position divs. I think if you check my jsfiddle you will immediately see what I'm doing wrong, but here's a breakdown to be specific:

I've got 2 fixed position divs, .menu and .menu-2. I'd like my .middle div to be underneath those, however at the moment its beneath that fixed position divs. Do I have any choice but to use absolute positioning? I'm going to eventually need to float a bunch of stuff inside my .left and .right divs.

I'd just like everything to begin after the fixed position divs. And lastly, my footer div also is underlapping and not being placed after my .middle div. Can someone explain where I'm going wrong here? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/5MW7s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: both;` to `footer`.
Add `margin-top: 120px !important;` to `.middle`.